# A custom list control with timepicker like UI

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am in need of a timepicker-like list control whose unselected elements are only shown when the user clicks on one. Something like the image below, however, I only need the central list and not the whole timepicker.

Is there any control that has similar functionality? Or else how can build one?

[image]

**EDIT - Using ComboBox as suggested by Nasser AlNasser**

So I tried editing the default style of ComboBox and pretty much achieved the look I wanted. However there is a small issue.

The dropdown appears like this when I run app on local machine:

[image]

And on the simulator:

[image]

Here is ComboBox style:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxVerticalDialStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,5,0,7"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#78797b"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxDropDownHeight" Value="200"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF78797B"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SplitOpenThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SplitCloseThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeFontWeight}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeMargin}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                    <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <FontIcon x:Name="DropDownGlyph" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="0"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am unable to figure out the issue here. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ComboBox` control is the best option for you, it's a part of the official XAML controls for UWP:
[image: combobox-uwp]

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FontsCombo" Header="Fonts" Height="44" Width="296">
  //bind the ItemSource, or:
  <ComboBoxItem Content="Font A" />
  <ComboBoxItem Content="Font B" />
</ComboBox>
```

Read more about it here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.aspx

Also, you can find the default styling here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299116.aspx

Which gives you ability to re-style it as you prefer :).

Comment: I kind of need something that looks like a looping control. A comboBox is a dropdown only and it doesn't give the overall feel of a loop.

Comment: Have you tried it?  combobox as a loop control by default

Comment: Took me some time to figure it out but it works! Thanks :)

Comment: However there is a tiny bit of a problem that I am unable to solve, the dropdown of the combobox has this tendency to position itself to the right and the offset is considerable in simulator vs local machine.  I am updating my question, please have a look..

Comment: This issue is now solved. I changed the MinWidth of ScrollViewer according to the width of the items I am using.